# What causes Android Studio error EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE?

Tags: android, c++

I am working with Android Studio and compiling a project that has both Java code and C++ files.  When I run my project and program execution goes into my C++ code, the app comes to a halt and I get this error:

```
E/EGL_emulation: tid 353: eglChooseConfig(962): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
```

What exactly triggers the EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE error so that I have a guess as to what to start looking at in my code?  I should mention also that my C++ code executes just fine in a Visual Studio 2017 project (I would try to include the code, but I'll go over the character limit here).

Comment: It looks like you are using OpenGL somewhere in your application. If so, can you please add your code where you call the method eglChooseConfig()? Note that this is probably a Java method. You should also consider adding “OpenGL” tag to your question.

Comment: My C++ appx. does this (function Load is a class member func, all 'obj' are STL containers for which the 'clear' method is defined):
`void myNamespace::myClass::Load(const char *file) {
ifstream qFile;
this->value1 = 0;
this->value2 = 0;
this->obj1.clear();
this->obj2.clear();
qFile.open(file);
if (qFile.is_open()) {
// do stuff (that is commented out for testing)
}
else while (1) ;
}`
If I completely comment out the if-else clause, the code runs fine.  Files are opened and closed without issue in a function called before this one.  OpenGL calls are not done by my code